# How to know that I am in mainnet or not?

Tags: metamask, infura

I use Metamask. Until now I used the goerli testnet network for my development project. I use `ethers.js` also in my project. Now how can I implement a test for knowing the network if it is goerli or the main network Ethereum ? Here is my code, but I dont see any clue for my needs :

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider();
  let ntwrk = await provider.getNetwork();
  console.log("============= selected network =", ntwrk);
}

main();
```

At runtime the console log shows :

```
{
  name: 'homestead',
  chainId: 1,
  ensAddress: '0x....',
  _defaultProvider: [Function: func] { renetwork: [Function (anonymous)] }
}
```

When I change the network then the name is always 'homestead', and the chainId is always 1

**edit :**

full code

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

async function main() {
  // Configuring the connection to an Ethereum node
  const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider(
    
  );
  let ntwrk = await provider.getNetwork();
  console.log("============= selected network =", ntwrk);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you provided, the InfuraProvider is created without any network specified, so it connects to the mainnet by default.

The line

```
let ntwrk = await provider.getNetwork();
```

If you wanted to connect to a different Ethereum network, such as the Goerli testnet, you would need to specify the network when creating the `InfuraProvider`

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

async function main() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider(
    "goerli", // Specify the Goerli testnet
    "your-infura-project-id" // Replace with your Infura project ID
  );

  let ntwrk = await provider.getNetwork();
  console.log("============= selected network =", ntwrk);
}

main();
```

It should work for you now. Just make sure to get your project ID from infura

Comment: The chainId is still 1 whenether the network is mainnet or goerli. So what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: can you share full code? or env file or config file

Comment: I updated the post to include the full code, the env file, named `.env`, is empty.

Comment: Adding an updated answer have a look at that !

Comment: sorry : I misplaced the code when I tried to update my post ; I didnt realize it was yours

Comment: No Worries ! Just check my answer now

Comment: is `homestead` referring to the `mainnet` network ?

Comment: `ChainId : 1` is reffering to mainnet

Comment: there is something strange in my runtime : the metamask network is goerli but the chainId is 1. How is that possible ?

Comment: Actually in your code you are not fetching network id from Metamask
Instead you are fetching that by putting your project ID of infura

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143214/discussion-between-talha-sajid-chaudhary-and-pheromix).